# How to use snippet for remark method in linqpad?

Tags: linqpad, linqpad5

e.g,in visual studio i can type `///` on top of method then system will generate

```
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xxx"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
```

But it's not work for LINQPad. How to use snippet for remark method in linqpad ?
I've tried to search `LINQPad Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts` but not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JoeAlbahari's answer :

> This feature is available in LINQPad 6, but not LINQPad 5. Note that it generates a simplified XML comment, i.e.:
>
> ///

from :
[How to use snippet for remark method in linqpad? — LINQPad](https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/2192/how-to-use-snippet-for-remark-method-in-linqpad#latest)